# how to create resizable control with multiple buttons in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, controls

I'm trying to build something like that

http://i58.tinypic.com/2rbyn1k.png

And I did something which is not really symmetrical and not resizable.
I would be grateful for some advices or solutions how to do this.

Comment: You should post your code not just ask for a solution.

Comment: I did something which is not really useful, so i didn't post the code. I used Path to create all shapes. Just saying that it's not like "hey, guyz, Im so lazy and plz givvve me solutionz", but I'm stuck in the topic and I'm trying to find out how to do this rightly

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Radial Menu project on github](https://github.com/Julien-Marcou/RadialMenu). With some tweeking you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I'll check this out, seems like it's exacly what I'm looking for. thx